# activescaffold belongs_to relationship giving routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, belongs-to, activescaffold

I am using the following:
Rails 3.0.3
Vhochstein's Fork for Activescaffold
rake 0.9.0
ruby 1.9.2

I have a model called component which has a belongs_to relationship with category. This was modelled using activescaffold and was working quite well. I took a break for a couple of months and now that I got back to it activescafold gives a 
"ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass):" error whenever I try to access the component model.
I figured this is due to the relationship (belongs_to). If i remove the relationship from the model, it works. If I add it back it fails!

Any Ideas?

Here is the Code:

### Routes

```
  namespace :admin do 
resources :users,:roles,:vendors,:shipping_modes,:order_types,:sizes,
          :suppliers,:categories,:sub_categories, :material_types,:colours,
          :materials,:styles,:surcharges, :budget_templates, :budget_components do
  as_routes      
end
```

end

### Controller

```
class Admin::BudgetComponentsController < ApplicationController
layout 'site_admin'

active_scaffold :budget_component do |config|
  config.actions.exclude :delete,:update
  config.columns[:category].form_ui = :select 
  config.create.columns = [:name,:category]
  config.list.columns = [:name,:category]
  config.show.columns = [:name,:category]
  config.show.columns.add_subgroup "Time Details" do |name_group|
    name_group.add :created_at,:updated_at
  end

  config.list.sorting = {:name => 'ASC'}    
end
end
```

### Model

```
class BudgetComponent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category

  validates_presence_of :name, :category_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :name
end
```

Comment: Probably a little late, but is this using cancan? I just had this issue, and it was because of a badly named relationship in cancan ability.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The solution is to add your `nil:NilClass` again, then it will work.

Comment: What does it mean to "add your nil:NilClass again"?